# How to delete line 7 in a file in Bash with sed?

Tags: command-line, bash, unix

How to delete line 7 in a file in Bash?

I tried

```
$ sed -i '7d' ~/demo
error:sed: 1: "~/demo": command a expects \ followed by text
```

Comment: The following works for me: `sed -i '' '7d' ~/demo`

Comment: `VAR=7; sed -i '' "${VAR}d" ~/demo`

Answer (score 1):

From `man sed`:

```
SYNOPSIS
     sed [-Ealnru] command [-I extension] [-i extension] [file ...]
```

So if you use `-i` you also need to specify an extension for the backup file. If you don't want a backup file to be created but still edit in-file, use `''`.

```
sed -i '' '7d' ~/demo
```

To take the number of the line to be deleted from a variable, use

```
DELETE_LINE=7
sed -i '' "${DELETE_LINE?}d" ~/demo
```

`$(VAR?}` makes the shell throw an error if the variable isn't set. This avoid running the command without a line number (which would delete all lines).

PS: Interestingly enough, `sed '7d' -i '' ~/demo` does not work (even though the synopsis implies it should). `sed -e '1d' -i '' ~/demo` does though.

Comment: RE: "SYNOPSIS sed [-Ealnru] command [-I extension] [-i extension] [file ...]" --  Note that this synopsis only ships with **macOS Big Sur** and later and has _options_ not supported with `sed` shipped with **macOS Catalina** and earlier.